# Join 2 tables using Spring JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities(Invoice and InvoiceItems) without adding any relationship.

Invoice

```
public class Invoice {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long invoiceID;

        @Column(name="code")
        private String code;

       //other columns
    }
```

Invoice Items

```
public class InvoiceItems {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long invItemID;

    @Column(name="invoice_id")
    private Integer invoiceId;

    //other columns
}
```

Can I join these entities and get data without adding relationship using JPA?
If it isn't possible how to join 2 entities using JPQL or Native query?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is valid then using native query you can do that

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, "select * from Invoice i join InvoiceItems im on i.id = im.invoice_id")
public List<Invoice> findData();
```

But that is not a good way join without relation using JPA.

Comment: Did you try this solution ?  or still facing  any issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can join these entities and get data without adding relationship using JPA, but it's a little bit losing the purpose of using JPA.

You need to create a java class first, which will be the returning data object from the DB. After that you can use entityManager's createNamedQuery method to get the result.

```
createNamedQuery(String sqlString, ResultClass.Class)
```

sqlString may be  something like:

```
SELECT INV.INVOICE_ID
       INV.CODE
       INV_ITEMS.INV_ITEM_ID
  FROM INVOICE INV
  JOIN INVOICE_ITEMS INV_ITEMS
    ON INV.INVOICE_ID = INV_ITEMS.INVOICE_ID;
```

And the corresponding ResultClass:

```
public class ResultClass {

    private Long invoiceID;
    private String code;
    private Long invItemID;

    // other columns
}
```

Or you can even use RowMapper to map the object all by yourself for more flexibility by using JdbcTemplate with query() method.